# Programmatically adding role with database permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ssas

I'm trying to add a role to my SSAS DB, but I'm having issues when I try to set the database permissions.

The following code will run without error

```
var server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server();
server.Connect("localhost\\SQLSERVER2012");

var database = server.Databases["LRTabDB"];
var role = database.Roles.Add(database.Roles.GetNewName("DataHubRole"));
var databasePermission = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DatabasePermission
{
    RoleID = role.ID,
    ID = role.Name,
    Name = role.Name,
    Read = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ReadAccess.Allowed
};
database.DatabasePermissions.Add(databasePermission);

var member = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.RoleMember { Name = "NETWORK SERVICE" };
role.Members.Add(member);

role.Update();
databasePermission.Update();
database.Update();
```

But when I attempt to look at the Role in SQL Server Management Studio I get the following error message

> Cannot show requested dialog.
>   Additional information:
>     Key cannot be null.
>     Parameter name: key (System)

If I remove the creation of the `databasePersmisson` object then I can view the role in Management Studio.  But ultimately I need to set the database permissions for the role.  I've also attempted getting the permissions, but the following just returns `null`.

```
 database.DatabasePermissions.FindByRole(role.ID);
```

I've also tried using the following to create the database permissions and got the same results.

```
var databasePermissions = database.DatabasePermissions.Add(
    database.DatabasePermissions.GetNewName(role.Name));
```

Finally I've also tried using a different Name and ID for the database permission from the role but again that does not help.

I assume there is some step that I'm missing, but the examples I've found for doing this don't shed any light on the problem.

https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/ssas-using-amo-to-secure-analysis-service-cube/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how can I get your error, but I've done something, what works for me.

Here is the code:

```
Server server = new Server();
server.Connect("Data source=" + cubeServerName + ";Timeout=7200000;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

Database db = server.Databases.FindByName(cubeName);

if (db.Roles.Find("MyRole") == null)
{
    Role newRole = db.Roles.Add("MyRole");
    RoleMember r = new RoleMember(userDomain + "\\" + userName);
    newRole.Members.Add(r);
    newRole.Update();
}

DatabasePermission dbperm;

var role = db.Roles.Find("MyRole");

dbperm = db.DatabasePermissions.Add(role.ID);
dbperm.Process = true; //I want to add process permission
dbperm.Update();
```

I used tutorial from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345081.aspx).